# Ruby, merge two different objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to merge to different object in my Ruby on Rails application. I have my Invoice object:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base {
                           :id => :integer,
                      :user_id => :integer,
                  :description => :text,
                             ......
                       :status => :string,
                        :price => :float
}
```

And my Payment object:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base {
            :id => :integer,
         :token => :string,
    :invoice_id => :integer,
    :created_at => :datetime,
    :updated_at => :datetime,
         :email => :string
}
```

With 1 to many relationship between them:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
```

Now what I would like to do is to return the Invoice object and the :email and :created_at field of the payment object associated. Right now I return the two object with the zip function:

```
:invoices => (user.invoices.where(:hide => false).zip user.invoices.map{|x| x.payments.last}),
```

but that return an array of array:

```
[
    [{invoice},{payment}],
    [{invoice},{payment}],
    ...
]
```

What I want to return is something like:

```
[
    {invoice, :email_payment, :created_at_payment},
    {invoice_1, :email_payment, :created_at_payment},
    ...
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Couldn't you create `email_payment` and `created_at_payment` methods in your `Invoice` class and use only `invoice` object?

Comment: Yes but from a logical point of view this does not make much sense, I hoped that there would be a better solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add `email_payment` and `created_at_payment` as methods to the invoice model, but you can achieve it with the following:

```
user.invoices.where(hide: false).map do |invoice|
  invoice.attributes.merge({ 
    email_payment: invoice.payments.last.email,
    created_at_payment: invoice.payments.last.created_at
  })
end
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted!